# defining a list as a rule and then getting the first element in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

If not very familiar with Prolog, but we're using the programming language as an extent for another developed very unknown programming language. and my problem is the following. I am well aware of the fact that i can write in the Prolog query

```
([Head|Tail]) = ([a,b,c]).
```

and this will result in me getting

```
Head = a, Tail = b,c.
```

However, this is not quite what I need.
I am writing a bot which receives from the program a list. the list is basically something the bot has to walk over and find every element of the list in the program, call it an environment. Now my problem is the following:

I don't seem to be able to define some rules for how to get the first element of that list. Ive been trying all sorts of things. at first the statement :

```
parameterList([a,b,c,d].

nextElement(X) :- parameterList(Z), member(Z,X).
```

doesn't seem to work. Why is this not working? and I'll ask the next in advance as well since i haven't been able to figure out either. from the environment i get a parameter indexOfNextElement(B). this returns a value of which element of the list i need to retrieve. Of course it starts at 0, and once this one has been delivered by the bot, the index goes up (this goes automatically).

Again i am very new to Prolog, so there's a good chance I am doing all of the syntaxes wrong, but it would be amazing to help me figure out a way to do it

Comment: It should be `member(X, Z)`.

Comment: In `([Head|Tail]) = ([a,b,c]).` the parentheses are superfluous. You can just write `[Head|Tail] = [a,b,c].` Your comment says, *I don't seem to be able to define some rules for how to **get the first element of that list**.* But your example query before that will do just that. If you have a list,`L`, then `L = [First|Rest]` will result in `First` being the first element of `L`, and `Rest` being the rest of the list. In your subsequent question, you say, *from the environment i get a parameter `indexOfNextElement(B)`*. It's unclear what you mean by "from the environment".

Answer (score 3):

The way you are placing the arguments in member/2 `[a,b,c,d]` is the member in the list `Z`. Hence when querying it you get the variable `X` substituted by lists:

```
   ?- nextElement(X).
X = [[a,b,c,d]|_A] ? ;
X = [_A,[a,b,c,d]|_B] ? ;
...
```

If you flip the arguments:

```
nextelement(X) :-
   parameterList(Z),
   member(X,Z).
```

The result is what I think you want:

```
   ?- nextelement(X).
X = a ? ;
X = b ? ;
X = c ? ;
X = d ? ;
no
```

As for getting the element at the nth position: this is basically a relation between a list an index and the element at that index:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

list_nth_element(L,N,E) :-
   list_nth_element_(L,N,E,0).         % the first index is 0

list_nth_element_([H|_T],N,H,N).       % element at index N
list_nth_element_([_H|T],N,E,Pos0) :-
   N #> Pos0,                          % position differs from index
   Pos1 #= Pos0 + 1,                   
   list_nth_element_(T,N,E,Pos1).      % E must be in the tail
```

You can query this different ways. Which elements are at what indices?:

```
   ?- list_nth_element([a,b,c,d],N,E).
E = a,
N = 0 ? ;
E = b,
N = 1 ? ;
E = c,
N = 2 ? ;
E = d,
N = 3 ? ;
no
```

Which element is at index 1?:

```
   ?- list_nth_element([a,b,c,d],1,E).
E = b ? ;
no
```

At which position is element `c`?:

```
   ?- list_nth_element([a,b,c,d],N,c).
N = 2 ? ;
no
```

In general, if you want to do something with *all* elements of the list, you can follow such a pattern:

```
predicatename([],...).
predicatename([H|T], ...) :-
    % do something with H here
    predicatename(T,...).
```

Note the `...` in the head of the rules and the recursive goal. This is where you place the additional arguments of your relation (see list_nth_Element/3 above). Depending on what you want to query, you leave the according argument as a variable and Prolog will substitute that variable with solutions to the relation, one at a time (see example queries above).

Concerning your comment: The queries above are just some examples of how you can use list_nth_element/3. Of course you can also use it as a goal in your robot predicate:

```
robotpredicatename(...) :-
   ...
   % you get the list somewhere here
   ...
   list_nth_element(L,N,E),
   ...
```

Somewhere before the goal list_nth_element/3 your predicate gets the list of interest and binds it to a variable, say `L`. After the list is available you can use list_nth_element/3 and `L` to get the element at the desired position. Or you can use the pattern above to write a predicate instead of list_nth_element/3 that does something with every element of the list.

Comment: The biggest issue with this sulution is, i dont have a prolog query i can use. So I can't define a list in the prolog query. In stead my robot is evaluating the list. It knows the elements in the list, and it knows what element to recieve. I just can't find a proper way to put this all in one rule the next_element(Element) rule